# How do I use OData with RIA services

Tags: ria, odata

When using RIA services, how do I specify I want to use OData instead of a proprietary format?

Comment: Please note, that you can only expose [read-only OData endpoint](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-10-Exposing-Domain-Services-To-Other-Clients.aspx) using RIA services.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new with Odata but currently works on RIA and I found the article from Brad Abrams blog at

http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2010/03/16/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-exposing-odata-services.aspx

After finished prepare everything such a service, you can specify to use OData by calling URL to the DomainService like

**"http://localhost:7777/Sample-App-GreatDomainService.svc/OData/YourObject"**

Which,

1. Sample-App-GreatDomainService.svc = Your domainservice namespace(Mine is Sample.App.GreatDomainService) and followed by .svc **(see that '.' replaced by '-')**
2. /OData/YourObject = Exposed to the typename in your data model as OData **(Mine is "YourObject" type)**

This will get an Atom Feed data of type "YourObject" in your project.

Hop this help. ^ ^